# SqlAlchemy sql.text lift limit clause

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have python3 + flask + sqlalchemy + postgres

I have a bunch of custom queries whose data I'm serving paginated as json.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.engine.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset',
                   limit=limit, offset=offset)
```

I can pass integer values for `limit` and `values`, so far so good.

However, I sometimes need the full data instead of paginated data.

The equivalent query for that would be

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT ALL OFFSET 0
```

So, I tried to pass `limit='ALL'` and `offset=0`

and SQLAlchemy complains

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for integer: "ALL"
LINE 1: ...T_LABEL_ID IN (2, 5) ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_RAW LIMIT 'ALL' OFFS...
```

`ALL` is a reserved keyword and not expected to be passed as a string

My question is if there is a better way to do this other than conditionally adding `LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset` to my query only when required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do something like that would be to assign an arbitrarily huge number. Something like this

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.engine.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset',
                   limit=99999999999999, offset=offset)
```

There is [another way if your database is postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html) which you have already tried. i.e. adding `LIMIT ALL`. Since you are getting error I pressume you are using Mysql or some other database.

**Update:**

As mentioned by Sundeep the error is due to string replacement. So an alternate way would be.

```
db.engine.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT {limit} OFFSET {offset}'.format(limit='ALL', offset=offset))
```

Comment: This is a good alternative and it works. I am using postgres, however `ALL` is a [reserved key word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and setting the parameter value to `'ALL'` makes it a string and hence the error.

Comment: the other way would be `db.engine.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT {limit} OFFSET {offset}'.format(limit='ALL', offset=offset))`

Comment: Perhaps a better option would be to *not* format *values* to SQL, but the ALL keyword/limit placeholder.